# How to fetch data at the moment the database updates, without refreshing the page, in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, database, websocket, django-channels

In a web application that I'm building using Django, there is a filed in the main page that fetches a price float from the database and shows it, and I need it to be updated **every time** that the source price (in the database) gets updated, **or within some seconds**. And I need that to be **without refreshing the page**, kind of **live** you can say.

Is there any possible way to reach this **without using Django channels**, e.g. by using JavaScript or anything else?

Comment: Why not? Set up a url endpoint in Django which will be repeatedly called by a Javascript function. You will probably need JSON response on the Django's back-end and Javascript's fetch() and setInterval() on the front-end. You will repeatedly get new data with fetch() and then insert it into the HTML.

Comment: @SergueiA Tank you man, would you please post this as an answer (not comment), and include some code and details in it?

Comment: your question is too broad, so I can't post a definite answer, that would require building all code base from scratch. 
What you need is "Ajax". Just look it up "Django Ajax".  There're many examples.
And then, in the case you don't understand something, ask more specific questions.

Comment: @SergueiA man it worked with Ajax! thank you so much for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@SergueiA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19315471/serguei-a) suggested in a comment, I searched for `Django Ajax` and found [this vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TXtsTutoQQ). And **YES IT WORKED!**

Using JavaScript and `setInterval()`, the price is updating every second now.